# How can I restart WPF application?

Tags: wpf

How can I restart WPF application from code? in Windows Forms there is Application.Restart, where for whatever reason Microsoft decided not to add this method in WPF.

I hate the discompatability between WPF and WindowsForms! like:

```
            window.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

What's wrong with that?

```
            window. Visible = false;
```

Comment: These are two separate questions.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773632/how-do-i-restart-a-wpf-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart application using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895188/restart-application-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

**Visibility**

For controls and panels, there is a huge difference between `Visibility.Collapsed` and `Visiblity.Hidden`. Hidden reserves the space of the invisible element, Collapse frees the used space. This can make a big difference in an UI.

Using the same enumeration for the visibility of the window-class is IMO first of all a question of holding a constancy in the class-library, but may be it makes also some other finer differences.

**Restart**

If there is a possibility to directly restart the app, I don't know. What you can try is to use `App.Current.Shutdown()` to close the app and start a new instance through `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` where the path to the app can be taken from `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`. `.