# Restart application using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I restart my WPF application using C#?

Comment: What do you mean by 'restart'?

Comment: very simple close it and restart it automatically :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct method in WPF like there is in WinForms. However, you could use methods from the `Windowns.Form` namespace like this: (You might need to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Form` assembly)

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();

System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Don't know what this is meant to achieve, in my case it reopens many instances of the same app without closing the first instances.

Answer (score 17):

The code

```
Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
```

does not work for .NET Core 3.1 applications. Instead use

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

...

Process.Start(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

This works also for .NET Framework applications.

Comment: Thanks, 
I am using 3.1 but `Application.Current.Shutdown()` wasn't available so I used `Application.Exit()` instead

Comment: Isn't there a chance the new instance might start before the old one has closed, especially if it has a lot of "housekeeping" to do? That could be problematic depending on the nature of the application, e.g. if it locks resources such as files, databases, ports, etc.

Answer (score 14):

The following is the best solution I found, you don't need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, instead you need add the namespace `System.Diagnostics` which you already has a reference to its assembly:

```
Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Note that you don't want to use this method if your application is deployed with ClickOnce. The `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` will be false when you restart. See http://bit.ly/RKoVBz for more info. If your application is not deployed with ClickOnce, this method works great.

Comment: @blachniet Also, you will start the *old* version after an update if using this method. This issue is also avoided when using the winforms method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Windows API Code Pack](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1)'s Restart and Recovery API.  Just be aware that this is a new API, so it will only work on current operating systems (i.e.: Windows 7).

Comment: Unfortunately, old and stale by now.

Answer (score 0):

The approaches mentioned here of launching a new instance before shutting down the current instance may be problematic, especially if the current instance takes a while to close (e.g writing to files/databases, disposing of resources, etc). The new instance might try to access those same resources, resulting in problems.

What I've done in my application is when I want to shut down:

```
((App)Application.Current).RestartRequired = true;
Application.Current.ShutDown();
```

Then in my `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public bool RestartRequired { get; set; }

....

protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnExit(e);

    if (RestartRequired)
    {
        Process.Start(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this will start the new instance as near to the current instance closing as is possible, and therefore avoid the problems mentioned above.