# WPF application restart

Tags: c#, wpf, restart

I have to restart an application. When I googled about it I found
[this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjT57molbnpAhVLwAIHHUtfDXcQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4773632%2Fhow-do-i-restart-a-wpf-application&usg=AOvVaw3cTZK27XZWzqRVyizEPQEM) and several others suggesting this code:

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
 System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();`

but all it did, was closing the application. I tried it within Visual Studio, and just executing the exe in the bin folder, but it always turned out the same.
The project is a .NET Core WPF.
Any additional ideas, or ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart application using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895188/restart-application-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should try to get the process rather than the assembly, which can return a *.dll*.

Restart the current application:

```
var currentExecutablePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
Process.Start(currentExecutablePath);
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```